# how to avoid Intersection of polygons via python code

Tags: qgis, python, polygon, intersection, snapping

i am using QGIS 1.8 and i can set the check box in Setting\Snapping Options "Snapping and Digitizing " dialog to avoid polygon intersections and enable topological editing but i am looking for a way to achieve the same via python code. is there any way to do it with python ?.

Thanks ,
Mael